# Eloquent Count nested relationships with nested eager loading

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, eloquent, eager-loading

You must have seen the following feature (on facebook), a post with some comments, each comment has a like counter.

https://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/67853820170616003640LaravelNewsAccueil.png

In laravel it would be something like

- Post hasMany Comment
- Comment belongsTo Post
- CommentLike belongsTo User
- CommentLike belongsTo Comment
- Comment hasMany CommentLike

So, now I want to get 10 posts with their comments, with the like counter per comment.

```
Post::with('comments')->withCount('comments.likes')->take(10)->get();
```

This does not work at all.

```
Post::with('comments')->withCount('comments')->take(10)->get();
```

This counts all comments for each post, I want to count all likes per comment on each post.

Answer (score 36):

Try this

```
Post::with(['comments' => function($query){
   $query->withCount('likes');
}])->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: is there a way to get the total count of likes instead of the count per comment?
Something to be able to get the via `$post->likes_count` or similar

Comment: Doesn't this require a `return` statement?

Comment: @Dharman the query object (like all objects) is passed by reference, so the closure isn’t expected or needed to return anything in order to modify the object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption `CommentLike` represents a `comment_likes` table

```
Post::with('comments' => function($query){
    $query->select('comment_likes.*')
          ->join('comments', 'comments.id', '=', 'comment_likes.comment_id')
          ->groupBy('comments.id')    
          ->havingRaw('sum(comment_likes.id) as likes')
}])->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: nice i'll try this ! but is there not an "eloquent" way to do this ? without raw query ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge with the sum(...) function.